# Why does Ods trace not work in SAS Macro?

Tags: macros, sas

When I run the below code as a macro, I can not create the dataset zcorr (using ods output). What am I doing wrong?

When I run the same code not as a macro (ie for Nov 2014 and Dec 2014 separately) there is no problem.

I'd like to fix the macro because I have to run the code for many more months. Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

```
%MACRO RunProgram(month, year);
data sourceh.trades2;
set sourceh.trades_&month.&year.;
if time<34200000 or time>57600000 then delete;

proc sort data=sourceh.trades2;
by symbol day month year int1;
run;


proc corr data=sourceh.trades2; by symbol day; 
var zbuy zsell;
ods output pearsoncorr=sourceh.zcorr;
run;


%MEND ;

%RunProgram(Dec, 2014);
%RunProgram(Nov, 2014);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ODS OUTPUT statement should be within or before the proc. The ODS TRACE statement does not generate any tables/results so you can remove those statements.

You should also be careful with comments in a macro and use '%* comment;' rather than just an asterisk.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your suggestion solved my problem! I also needed to add another step to this program but I think I am doing something wrong. I added another variable to the first data step called int. It would be great if I could run this program for each month, year and int combination. I tried to update the macro but I think something is wrong. Would you be able to take a look at my updated code in the original question and let me know if I'm making a mistake? If I should be asking this as a separate question on this forum, I can do that, too. Thanks so much!

Comment: @BetsyB Yes, you should create a new question, make sure to include your corrected updated code.